# Reliable QTcpSocket::write without waitForBytesWritten

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I am confused by a number of aspects of `QTcpSocket::write`.

- The documentation suggests that it can write fewer bytes than the length of the buffer being sent. This implies that multiple calls are potentially needed. What is the recommended way to deal with this (bearing in mind following points)?
- My initial attempt at calling `write` did not appear actually to send any data. I found that calling `waitForBytesWritten` solved this. If I need multiple write calls as per previous point, how do I use `waitForBytesWritten` in conjunction with these? Do I associate a `waitForBytesWritten` with each write or do I loop over `write` and then use `waitForBytesWritten`.
- The documentation suggests that `waitForBytesWritten` can fail randomly on Windows so *ideally* I do not want to rely on it at all. It suggests using the `bytesWritten` signal instead but I have found very little information on how one is supposed to use this properly. In particular, if I have to deal with my concern in the first point, do I not get into the recursive call situation warned about in the documentation of `bytesWritten`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [loopback example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-loopback-example.html) in the `Qt` docs.

Comment: Thanks - that one is quite useful. It looks like `bytesWritten` can be used in the way that I had imagined.